# Is there an infrared sensor API exposed in the Windows Phone 7 SDK?

Tags: winapi, windows-phone-7, sensors, infrared

I can't find any infrared sensor API in the Windows Phone SDK.

Is there any infrared sensor in WP7 and is this API exposed to the developers?

EDIT: I am asking because the majority of mobile OSs have historically supported infrared communication (Symbian, iOS).

Comment: What makes you think there is an IR sensor on WP7?

Comment: Where you see infrared sensor on WP7? LOL

Comment: @Ku6opr The majority of mobile OSs have historically supported infrared communication (Symbian, iOS), this is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IR Sensor is not a standard feature on WP7 so there is no api exposed, if you do have one on your device then it is probably used by the oem for something but i can't see why they would have one.